# Symfony 3 modify slug gedmo annotation

Tags: symfony, annotations, slug

I have a field in my entity:

```
/**
  * slug field
  *
  * @Gedmo\Slug(fields={"name"})
  * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, unique=true)
  *
  * @var string
  */
 private $slug;
```

Now I want to modify this field to make slug from two fields.

```
/**
  * slug field
  *
  * @Gedmo\Slug(fields={"id", "name"})
  * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, unique=true)
  *
  * @var string
  */
  private $slug;
```

But when I saved this changes it still making slug only from field "name". How to save this annotation changes?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try if it is working for new entities? Old slugs will not be updated automatically after changing the config. You have to unset the slugs of all existing entities and save them again to generate new slugs. I used a Command to do this:

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Command;

use AppBundle\Entity\YourEntityClass;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\ContainerAwareCommand;

/**
 * Generates slugs again
 */
class UpdateSlugsCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand
{
    protected function configure()
    {
        $this
            ->setName('appbundle:update-slugs')
            ->setDescription('generate new slugs')
            ->setHelp('needed after changing the config');
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $em = $this->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getEntityManager();

        $entities = $em->getRepository(YourEntityClass::class)->findAll();
        foreach ($entities as $entity) {
            // unset slug to generate a new one
            $entity->setSlug(null);
            $em->persist($entity);
        }
        $em->flush();
    }
}
```